# This is a Mensa IQ test from Norway. The last puzzle.

Tags: pattern, geometry

[image]

I solved all of the questions except this one. I checked and the answer in the bottom left one. I couldn't find any pattern or relations that would help me understand why or how one reaches the answer. Maybe you can. Would mean a lot to me if I got this right.

Comment: It's not the bottom left...

Comment: Flip the image in the first row vertically, XOR it with the second row, that gives the third row (the vertical dashed line is a giveaway)... appears to be the bottom right that's the correct one. I don't have image editing tools at hand now, so someone else is welcome to expand this into an answer. :-)

Comment: @noedne yes, sorry it's the bottom right actually

Comment: @Phylyp Can you please stare explicitly what XOR ing means ?

Comment: Thanks for the throwback to one of my earliest answers here :)

Comment: @ArpanSaha - When a line from the first row (after flipping) overlays a line in the second row, erase the line, else retain the line. Similar to the [XOR gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate) in digital logic, where if there's an input of 1 on both lines, the output is 0.